# Report Parameter to be filled out only when running the report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I think I'm trying to do the impossible here, but I thought to ask before giving up.

Essentially, I want to use a query that generates a unique ID for an instance of a report, and use that ID in subsequent datasets (to insert into a Global Temp table as a reference number).

All of the SQL code I've written works great; an ID is generated and returned, other queries can use the ID (if passed correctly) and so on and so forth. 
*However*, it doesn't work when inside a report.

When I make the ID generation script the available/default values for a parameter, the script runs prematurely (I want it to run when the user clicks `View Report`), and because it's a Global Temp table, sometimes it disappears after the report is run and doesn't get regenerated again (due to the ID script not being run again) and makes the report die.

Is there a way to delay the "filling in" of a parameter when done by a dataset until the report is actually run? I don't mind if it runs multiple times, so long as it gets run as the parent cascade of the rest of the datasets that use it every time the report is refreshed.

Comment: What you can do is make all the sections of the report that are dependent on the generated ID into subreports, and pass the ID to the subreports.

Comment: Ooh.... that's a lot of subreports (lots of datasets, the reason why I'm trying to profile performance)...

Comment: Could you consolidate all the sections into one subreport, and pass the ID to that?

Comment: That's certainly a possibility, I think I would need to mirror the parameters back into the parent report but it just might work.